# cdk CI/CD Pipeline - destroy duplicate stacks

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, continuous-deployment, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I'm working on setting up a CI/CD Pipeline with cdk in typescript. I have a very modular stack structure so I'm having a Stage with 3 stacks: LambdasStack, EndpointsStack and TablesStack. As the name suggest I have all my Lambdas in LambdasStack and so on.

For the pipeline I want the following flow:

1. Build
2. Deploy Stacks for PreProd
3. Integration Test
4. Destroy Stacks of PreProd
5. Manual approval before Prod
6. Deploy Stacks for Prod

The PreProd stacks have to be destroyed before the deployment of the Prod stacks because of the unique names of the tables within the TablesStack. And that's what I'm struggling with. My code to destroy them is:

```
const deletePreProdStacks= new ShellStep('Delete deployed Stacks', {
            commands: [
                'npm install',
                'cdk destroy -f --all'
            ]
 });
```

With `'cdk destroy -f --all'` the stacks of the stage are not found so they can't be deleted.

How can I solve this problem? Giving the tables autogenerated names can't be the right solution? Or is there an option to overwrite the PreProdStacks to ProdStacks?

I only have access to only one AWS Account. Because I read that having Testing/PreProd stage and Prod stage on different accounts.

Maybe someone has a similar best practice reference for me?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit1: tag update
Edit2: added situation about deployment of PreProd & Prod in same account

Comment: Are the `PreProd` stage's stack names different than the `Prod` stack names?  How are you setting the stack names in the deploy stages?

Comment: Yes, they are different. They will have a `PreProd- `or `Prod-` tag before their stack name. But the problem is, that the resources will have the same name eventhough their stack are not the same.
Maybe I can use the stack's name as a tag for the tables names?

Answer (score 2):

I found an ok solution for giving the resources that can't be duplicated different names by adding the stagename in their properties like this:

In the Stack:

```
const bookingsTable = new dynamodb.Table(this, 'BookingsTable', {
        tableName: `${stageTag}-BookingsTable`,
        partitionKey: {
            name: 'bookingId',
            type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING
        },
        billingMode: dynamodb.BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST
    });
```

In the Stage:

```
const tables = new TablesStack(this, `TablesStack`, {
        stageTag: this.stageName,
        env: {
            account: account,
            region: region
        }
    });
```

There by I create 2 tables one named `PreProd-BookingsTable` and the other `Prod-BookingsTable`.

So I don't need to destroy the already deployed stacks

Answer (score 2):

Your PreProd stage's stacks are not being destroyed because `cdk destroy` isn't getting the stack names right.  The `cdk destroy` command does the following:

1. Synths the App using the command in the `--app` flag or in the `app` key of `cdk.json`.
2. Gets the App's stack names.   The names are in the [cloud assembly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/apps.html#apps_cloud_assembly) output (specifically, in `cdk.out/manifest.json`) created in Step #1.
3. Calls the CloudFormation `DeleteStack` API for each stack name.

You want to destroy stacks like `PreProdLambdasStack`, but the `app.ts` is producing other stack names.  So nothing gets deleted.  One way to fix this is to pass the stage name to your app file as an environment variable.  Modify `app.ts` to concatenate the stage prefix to the base stack name to produce stacks with a stage name prefix like `PreProd`.

```sh
# ShellStep command
STAGE_PREFIX=PreProd && cdk destroy --app 'ts-node ./bin/app.ts' --all --force
```

Because `stage.ts` (stack creation) and `app.ts` (stack deletion) need the same stack code, keep your code DRY with a reusable stack-creation wrapper called in both contexts:

```js
// call this in the stages and in app.ts

export const makeAppStacks = (
  scope: cdk.App | pipelines.Stage,
  account: string,
  region: string,
  stageName?: string
): void => {
  const prefix = (stageName && stageName !== 'Prod') ? stageName : ''
  new LambdasStack(scope, `${prefix}LambdasStack`, {...})
  new EndpointsStack(scope, `${prefix}EndpointsStack`, {...})
  new TablesStack(scope, `${prefix}TablesStack`, {...})
};
```

#### Notes

The [AWS-recommended setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-organization) is a separate account for each environment.  If, however, you are stuck with a single account for `PreProd` and `Prod`, the next cleanest option is to have separate stacks per environment.  `PreProd` deploys and is tested, then is destroyed.  To speed up pipeline execution, the `Prod` deploy and `PreProd` destroy can run in parallel.

Another best practice is to [avoid assigning construct names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-names) at all, or AWS puts it, *"Use generated resource names, not physical names"*.  If pretty resource names are a requirement, consider assigning them only in `Prod` environments.

```js
tableName: props.isProd ? 'MyGreatTableName' : undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't need to destroy your stacks but specify physical names for resources  By “environment”  (not preferred).
By environment I mean the stage name, e.g. “pre-prod”, “prod”, etc.

The best solution is to deploy your testing & PreProd & Prod stages in difference accounts.
And if you're using CDK popelines, deploying to multiple accounts shoudn't be too much work, the only thing you have to do is bootstrap all the accounts you deploy to to trust the deployment account (review the bootstrapping docs) and set the account IDs in the stages.

Comment: Nice to see my slack messages are ending up as SO answers ;)